# How to set priorities in fonts?

Tags: xetex

I made my own font `geo_regular.ttf` where draw symbols as they are in LaTeX math mode, and I am using with `AozoraMinchoRegular.ttf` for japanese. Here is an example of my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{geo_regular.ttf}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{AozoraMinchoRegular.ttf}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=2.5cm,  left=1.7cm, right=1.7cm}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

います, あります.  日本語 იაპონია „435356“ ქართული

\end{document}
```

For some reson wile compiling (XeLaTeX) it uses `“0123456789` symbols and kanji uses from `AozoraMinchoRegular.ttf`, but I want to use only those characters from this font which are not defined in my font. Can it be done?

Comment: xetex does not automatically switch fonts, if you need different characters to switch fonts at some point then you need to use a font command as normal in latex. It may be possible to set xetex to add this automatically by using  `\newXeTeXintercharclass` and declaring character classes that should be in each font.

Comment: But, why does it read this `“0123456789` characters from cjk font, while `„,;?!` are read from main font?

Comment: xecjk has set up the characters to be in different classes and specified a font switch at the boundary I don't know the details of that package, sorry, but adding \tracingall after your text shows the use of tokens inserted at the boundaries between \c__xeCJK_HalfLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass1
\c__xeCJK_HalfRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass2
\c__xeCJK_NormalSpace_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass3
\c__xeCJK_CM_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass4
\c__xeCJK_HangulJamo_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass5